# Extract pid of browser launched by Selenium WebDriver in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

Does anyone know how to get the process id of the browser launched by Selenium WebDriver from the Ruby script that runs the WebDriver?

Answer (score 5):

The answer of Ben did not work for me, I had to adjust it to the following:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

bridge = driver.instance_variable_get(:@bridge)
service = bridge.instance_variable_get(:@service)
process = service.instance_variable_get(:@process)
process.pid
# => 22656
```

Comment: I think this is the pid of the (chromedriver), not the actual browser itself.

Comment: @BananaNeil I'm not sure, all I know is that killing this pid exited the (stuck) browser. Anyway, this was the only pid I was able to acquire.

Answer (score 2):

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox

bridge = driver.instance_variable_get(:@bridge)
launcher = bridge.instance_variable_get(:@launcher)
binary = launcher.instance_variable_get(:@binary)
process = binary.instance_variable_get(:@process)
process.pid
```

Answer (score 2):

Both answers didn't work for me, 'cause this is a part of private api. 
Checkout on [github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.8.1/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/service.rb#L41)

```
require "selenium-webdriver" # gem 3.9.0

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
pid    = driver.instance_variable_get(:@service)
               .instance_variable_get(:@process)
               .instance_variable_get(:@pid)
```

#### NOTE:

For anyone who trying to access browser by pid, e.g. to execute `kill -9 $pid` command. It maybe wrong, cause I came across to a better solution.

In command args we can pass custom attrs.
I use it like this

```
@buid   = SecureRandom.hex[0..15] # browser unique identifier
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new(
  args: [
    '-headless',
    "-buid=#{@buid}",
  ]
)
```

So then you can grep and kill both browser process and geckodriver.
By exec

```
$ps aux | awk '/-buid=$generated_pid/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Hope it helps!